# How do i call a function if a switch is off in customtkinter?

Tags: python, customtkinter

I know how to call a function if a switch is on but not when it is off. There is not a lot of documentation about customtkinter so il be happy to get an answer!

Iv tried different booleans and stuff but it did not work.

Comment: I've never worked with customtkinter, but would it be possible simply to add ``command=func`` similar to vanilla tkniters ``Tkinter.Button(parent, command=func)``?

Acording to this doc (https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkSwitch) ``command`` would do just that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
def led_switch(self, event=None):
    if self.is_on:
        print("The LED is on")
        self.is_on = False
    else:
        print("The LED off")
        self.is_on = True
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use custom Tkinter `command` argument as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkSwitch).

Slight variation of the docs example code in the docs:

```
switch_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="on")

def switch_event():
    print("switch toggled, current value:", switch_var.get())

switch_1 = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=root_tk, command=switch_event,
                                   variable=switch_var, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
```

Comment: You already gave a link to the documentation in the comment, why post a copy in the answer?

Comment: Why not? Does it take something away from the answer? In my mind it highlights possible solution still giving credit to source material. I would have taken more unnecessary things away from the code example, but I am not familiar with this library so I wouldn't want to remove anything essential from it. Is example necessary? Does it add information to the answer? Does it confuse the questioner? Subjective, but I would say no, yes and no.